# Mysql Query: Number of candidates enrolled and seat available

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am stuck with a mysql query. I have three tables:

Table Name : Teacher

```
teacherid  teachername 
 1001           ABC
 1002           XYZ
```

Table Name : batch

```
batchid   batchname  batch_type     class   batchinstructor     seat
   1        Solar        1            Five     1001               40
   2        Earth        2            Six      1002               40
```

Table Name: student

```
    studentid studentname batchid
     1          Bon Jovi     1
     2          Shane Warne  2
     3          John Denver  1
     4          Steve Wuagh  2
     5          Perterson    2
```

### What I want to achieve

```
 batchname class  teachername seat  students_enrolled  seat_available
   Solar   Five    ABC          40           2              38
   Earth   six     XYZ          40           3              37
```

I am using codeigniter and have managed to achieve all the things I have mentioned above accept for the column `students_enrolled`, `seat_available`

Here's the code what I have tried.

```
      function batch_list($perPage,$uri) { 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('batch');
    $this->db->join('teacher', 'batch.batchinstructor = teacher.teacherid');
    $this->db->order_by('batchid','DESC');
    $getData = $this->db->get('', $perPage, $uri);
    if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
    return $getData->result_array();
        else
        return null;
    }
```

Would you please kindly help me with the mysql query. please note that I am using Codeigniter.

thanks in advance

Comment: In your second row of what you want, shouldn't `Five` be `Six`?

Comment: You are right. Sorry for my mistake. I have made the correction. Thanks :)

Comment: The query you want is something like `SELECT b.batchname, b.class, t.teachername, b.seat, count(s.studentid) AS students_enrolled, b.seat - count(s.studentid) AS seat_available FROM batch b LEFT JOIN Teacher t ON t.teacherid = b.batchinstructor LEFT JOIN students s ON s.batchid = b.batchid GROUP BY s.batchid ORDER BY b.batchid DESC` - how that translates to CI I don't know... (**EDITED** I missed the `GROUP BY` clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure SQL, the query you want is:

```
SELECT
  b.batchname, b.class, t.teachername, b.seat,
  COUNT(s.studentid) AS students_enrolled,
  b.seat - COUNT(s.studentid) AS seat_available
FROM batch b
LEFT JOIN Teacher t ON t.teacherid = b.batchinstructor
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.batchid = b.batchid
GROUP BY s.batchid
ORDER BY b.batchid DESC
```

All you need to do is translate this CodeIgniter - as suggested by @Broncha, you can do:

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the query:

```
$sql = "select 
b.batchname,
b.class,
t.teachername,
b.seat,
count(s.id) as students_enrolled,
(seat - count(s.id)) as seat_available,
from batch b
join teacher t on t.teacherid = b.batchinstructor
join student s on s.batchid = b.batchid
group by s.batchid
order by b.batchid desc";
```

You can directly use it like this:

```
$this->db->query($sql);
```